# EF Code First, Repo & Unit of Work pattern - Cannot insert NULLS on primary key column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am using the Entity Framework Code First, Repository and Unit of Work pattern to transfer data from one database to another.  I need to maintain the unique identifier from the source database in the destination database so I am not letting the database handle record key management.

When I try to insert the records into the destination database, it is throwing the following EF data validation error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'MyPrimaryKey', table 'DestinationDb.db.MyTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT Fail.  The statement has been terminated

In my Model I am explicitly identifying the primary key property

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnontations.Schema;

[Table("MyTable")]
public new class MyTable
{
    [Key]
    public int MyPrimaryKey { get; set; }
}
```

When debugging the application, the value for `MyPrimaryKey` is being maintain during the whole process and throws the exception until I call the `SaveChanges()` method in my Destination database `DbContext.  Viewing the`DbContext`object while debugging, it has the value for`MyPrimaryKey` property.

Here is the source code:

```
public class DestinationEntities : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public DestinationEntities() : base("DestinationEntities") { }

    public DbSet<MyTable> MyTable { get; set; }

    public override int SaveChanges() 
    {
        return base.SaveChanges(); //exception thrown here
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    IDbSet<T> IDbContext.Set<T>() 
    {
        return this.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

Does anyone has experience with the scenario and how do I resolve issue?

Comment: Don't you have a dba to do this for you?

Comment: Try setting `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` on your destination entities' keys.

Comment: @Mardoxx Where should that option be set?  On the `MyTable` model or `DestinationEntities` object?

Comment: On the `MyPrimaryKey` property of `MyTable` e.g. `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` below `[Key]`

Comment: @Mardoxx That fixed my issue....thx!

Answer (score 0):

To credit [Mardoxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3515174/mardoxx) who posted the answer in the comments:

I had to add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` to the `MyPrimaryKey` property in the `MyTable` class

```
[Table("MyTable")]
public new class MyTable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int MyPrimaryKey { get; set; }
}
```